# Auto Scheduling in Microsoft Project Planning 2016 is not working as expected

Tags: planning, resource-planning

I scheduled many tasks in the AUTO schedule, However, it is not taking/changing the dates once I link all the tasks. Due to that, I selected the start date manually which is resulting in a different number of working hours for each day.

Find below a screenshot of the resource sheet.

Example: 7h, 6h, 16h, 13h, etc., [image]